# What causes a JDBC Type 91 error?

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, weblogic

I have a web app hosted on BEA Weblogic `10.x` with an Oracle 10g database backend.

It works perfectly with one database, but when we make a clone of it and try to use a different WebLogic and Oracle instance we are getting this error:

```
ERROR - Problem initializing invocation tracking - disabling 
tracking xxxxclass.BadTableMappingException: Database column 
xxxxPeriodEnding in database yyyyyyy, table zzzzzzz has an 
unknown type: JDBC Type 91.
```

We get it every time we do a query that involves a column of type `DATE`.  There was no `ORA-XXXX` code in the message.

I can access the database using SQL*Plus using the same access and do selects and updates on the same tables with no errors.

The answer to this question is not just a simple description of what a `type 91 error` is (although that will help) but what could be causing this given the circumstances described above.

I am using `ojdbc14.jar` for JDBC on both instances of weblogic.

Comment: Did you get a SQLException? if so, was there an ORA-XXXX code in the message?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the error, but have you considered the jdbc jar version and more importantly if the oracle DB needs to be updated.

I faced very weird problems with oracle, and struggled for a while to find at the end that installing some patches for oracle would solve the problem.

Comment: I do suspect the JDBC jar file but it is supposedly identical between the two weblogic instances. I will investigate this more in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Set `oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible=true`.

This remaps the oracle DATE type to a `DATETIME` time in JDBC.  This parameter was missing on the new Weblogic server.